# Issues with reshaping data from columns to factors with measured variables

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have tried several of the previous posts on this site with no success.  Essentially I have a dataset in the form of:

```
Year   Measurement
2006   25.5
2006   19.2
2005   10.3
2005   30.7
2005   15.5
2005   37.1
2004   10.2
2004   19.6
2004   11.7
```

And where I need to be is:

```
2006  2005  2004
25.5  10.3  10.2
19.2  30.7  19.6
NA    15.5  11.7
NA    37.1  NA
```

Ultimately, what I need is a box plot of the variables for each year, and to be able to perform a Duncan's test on the years.  I'd buy anyone a drink if they can help me out!  I have done something similar before, and cannot for the life of me find the code.

After trying the below suggestions:

```
> x <- df %>% 
+   group_by(Year) %>% mutate(idx = row_number())
>   spread(Year) %>% 
+   select("2006", "2005", "2004")
Error: Please supply column name
```

And the output table for x is:

```
> x
Source: local data frame [1,566 x 3]
Groups: Year [108]

    Year      SO4   idx
   <int>    <dbl> <int>
1   2007 26.34704     1
2   2007 90.44014     2
3   2007 46.90688     3
4   2007 49.58418     4
5   2007 74.22378     5
6   2007 40.61453     6
7   2006 60.19040     1
8   2006 53.03285     2
9   2006 44.14015     3
10  2006 29.36072     4
# ... with 1,556 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

x <- df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  spread(Year, Measurement) %>% 
  select("2006", "2005", "2004")
```

Output:

```
#   2006 2005 2004
# 1 25.5   NA   NA
# 2 19.2   NA   NA
# 3   NA 10.3   NA
# 4   NA 30.7   NA
# 5   NA 15.5   NA
# 6   NA 37.1   NA
# 7   NA   NA 10.2
# 8   NA   NA 19.6
# 9   NA   NA 11.7
```

Now you can produce your desired plot with `boxplot(x)`.

Comment: If you use a `group_by(Year) %>% mutate(idx = row_number())` instead of `rownames_to_column()` you'll get the desired output.

Comment: This gives: `> x <- df %>% 
+   group_by(Year) %>% mutate(idx = row_number())
>   spread(Year) %>% 
+   select("2006", "2005", "2004")
Error: Please supply column name`

Comment: If you provide a proper dataset with `dput` I can help you better.